Change auth0 user nickname with NextJs route handlers and server actions
I have NextJs project where I use auth0 for user authentication. What I am trying to do, is to make it possible for a user to change their username, using auth0 Management API. Here is the code below:
/api/change-usename/route.ts
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function PATCH(auth_id: string, newUsername: string) {
  const AUTH0_DOMAIN = process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const AUTH0_API_TOKEN = process.env.AUTH0_API_TOKEN;

  const url = `https://${AUTH0_DOMAIN}/api/v2/users/${auth_id}`;

  const myHeaders = new Headers({
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${AUTH0_API_TOKEN}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

  const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify({ username: newUsername }),
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorText = await response.text();
      throw new Error(`Failed to update user on Auth0: ${errorText}`);
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Username updated successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating user on Auth0:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error updating user on Auth0' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

/api.ts
export async function changeUserName(auth_id: string, newUsername: string) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/change-username/${auth_id}`, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ newUsername }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorText = await response.text();
      throw new Error(`Error ${response.status}: ${errorText}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to change username');
  }
}

/actions.ts
export async function changeUserNameAction(auth_id: string, newUsername: string) {
  try {
    await changeUserName(auth_id, newUsername);
    revalidatePath('/profile')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to change username');
  }
}

component UsernameInput.tsx
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { changeUserNameAction } from '@/app/actions.ts';
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function UsernameInput() {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const [newUsername, setNewUsername] = useState<string>('');


  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && user.nickname) {
      setNewUsername(user.nickname);
    }
  }, [user]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (user && user.sub) {
      try {
        const result = await changeUserNameAction(user.sub, newUsername);
        return result
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating username:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='flex flex-col gap-2 items-start'>
      <span className='font-bold text-lg text-gray-600'>Username</span>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='username'
        className='focus:outline-none focus:border-[1px] focus:border-light-orange username text-lg border-[1px] dark:bg-slate-800 rounded-xl px-[10px] py-[11px] border-slate-300 w-full'
        value={newUsername}
        onChange={(e) => setNewUsername(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type='submit'
        className='username-button py-[10px] px-[17px] bg-light-orange hover:bg-dark-orange transition-colors duration-300 rounded-xl text-white font-bold'
        id='username-button'
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}


here is the error I am receiving:
    Error updating user on Auth0: Error: Failed to update user on Auth0: {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Path validation error: 'Object didn't pass validation for format user-id: [object Request]' on property id (ID of the user to update).","errorCode":"invalid_uri"}
    at PATCH (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/change-username/[id]/route.ts:27:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53446
    at async e_.execute (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:44747)
    at async e_.handle (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54700)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1377:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1587:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
    at async C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13)
 PATCH /api/change-username/google-oauth2|109049551902929559745 500 in 1408ms
Error: Error: Error 500: {"message":"Error updating user on Auth0"}
    at changeUserName (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./api.ts:98:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async changeUserNameAction (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./app/actions.ts:101:9)
    at async C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:418
    at async rS (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:7978)
    at async r2 (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1251)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1438:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1587:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
    at async C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13)
Error: Error: Failed to change username
    at changeUserName (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./api.ts:105:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async changeUserNameAction (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./app/actions.ts:101:9)
    at async C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:418
    at async rS (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:7978)
    at async r2 (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1251)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1438:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1587:40)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
    at async C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\ucha\tbc-lectures\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13)
 ⨯ app\actions.ts (102:11) @ changeUserNameAction
 ⨯ Error: Failed to change username
    at changeUserNameAction (./app/actions.ts:105:15)
digest: "829804621"
  100 |   } catch (error) {
  101 |     console.error('Error:', error);
> 102 |     throw new Error('Failed to change username');
      |           ^
  103 |   }
  104 | }
  105 |
 POST /profile 500 in 1498ms

any help would be appreciated, since I am still new to all this backend stuff.
